# Two columns for grammar environment

Tags: listings, two-column, grammar

My grammar is long and thin. I'd like to space it out horizontally, as two columns.

```
\newenvironment{BNF}
  {\captionsetup{type=lstlisting}}
  {}

\begin{BNF}
\caption{My Grammar}
\label{grammar:my-grammar}
\begin{grammar}
<f> ::= "p"
\alt "true"
\alt "false"
\alt <f> <binop> <f>

<binop> ::= "U" (strong until)
 \alt "&&" (logical and)
 \alt $\rightarrow$ (implication)
 \alt $\leftrightarrow$ (equivalence)
\end{grammar}
\end{BNF}
```

I'd like it to be one Listing, with one caption. But I'd like `<f>` to be in the first column, and `<binop` to be in the second. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you turn your code fragment into a complete compilable document; it's much easier for people to play with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with the `multicol` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,caption,syntax}
\newenvironment{BNF}
  {\captionsetup{type=lstlisting}}
  {}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{BNF}
\caption{My Grammar}
\label{grammar:my-grammar}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{grammar}
<f> ::= "p"
\alt "true"
\alt "false"
\alt <f> <binop> <f>
\columnbreak

<binop> ::= "U" (strong until)
 \alt "&&" (logical and)
 \alt $\rightarrow$ (implication)
 \alt $\leftrightarrow$ (equivalence)
\end{grammar}
\end{multicols}
\end{BNF}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]